# Perl mysql mac address error

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I have the below perl extract:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (`MACADDR`) 
    VALUES ($MACADDR)";
    print $query,"\n";
    $db->do($query);
```

I got the below error when trying to insert to mysql and my mac address is 000E38F4E9CC:

```
DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0E38F4E9CC)' at line 2 at insertmac.pl line 156.
```

Is perl mysql dbi able to insert mac address?
My other records is able to be inserted correctly except mac addresses.

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about parameterized queries? If no, why is somebody letting you write SQL? (In other words, you have to quote the mac address. This is best done by using a placeholder instead of interpolating the value directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your passing in a string as a value you need to quote it

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO test (`MACADDR`) 
VALUES ('$MACADDR')";
```

Alternatively you can prepare it and use parameters

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO test (`MACADDR`) 
VALUES (?)";

  my $q = $db->prepare($query);
  $q->execute($MACADDR);
```

which is a better idea as you can reuse it for speed and it also avoid SQL injection attacks

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. Very much appreciated. I was quite unaware of the quotes as I'm not a progammer.